# Angular UI displaying white block while images load

Tags: html, css, angular, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following template:

```
<div *ngIf="article.likes" class="flex -space-x-2 my-5 mx-2">
  <img
    *ngFor="let img of article.likes"
    class="inline-block h-8 w-8 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white"
    [src]="AWS_CLOUDFRONT + img"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```

article.likes is loaded quickly so adding a skeleton like so:

```
<div *ngIf="article.likes; else skeleton" class="flex -space-x-2 my-5 mx-2">
  <img
    *ngFor="let img of article.likes"
    class="inline-block h-8 w-8 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white"
    [src]="AWS_CLOUDFRONT + img"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
<ng-template #skeleton>
  <app-skeleton></app-skeleton>
</ng-template>
```

hasn't been working for me. I know it's def this part of the template because removing it and refreshing the page doesn't show the white block. Does anyone a good way to display some sort of skeleton or temporary html while the images are loaded?

(This is also my first time using cloudfront so if the following:

```
[src]="AWS_CLOUDFRONT + img"
```

isn't a great idea, it'll also be appreciated)

Also, I'm not even sure why it's taking a while for them to load on subsequent reloads of the page, isn't the point of a cdn to cache this data? It takes the same amount of time to load every time I reload.